# Android DownloadManager Fails with reason 470

Tags: android, android-download-manager

- I am using android.app.DownloadManager to download files in fragment.
- I saved the download id when it begins. and I query the download status when I enter the fragment to see whether the file is downloading.

**The code in fragment is like this:**

```
long downloadId = viewModel.getDownloadId(); // the id downloaded last time.
DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId);
Cursor c = null;
int downloadStatus = -1;
try {
    c = manager.query(query);
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        downloadStatus = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
    }
} finally {
    if (c != null) {
        c.close();
    }
}
switch (downloadStatus) {
    case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
        //do something
        break;
    case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
    case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
    case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
        // register ContentObserver to receive download progress, I query the status in `onChage` methord.
        getContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
             Uri.parse("content://downloads/my_downloads"), true, mDownLoadChangeObserver);
        break;
    default:
        //show a button to download
}

//button click listener
button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    long id = manager.enqueue(request);
    // save the download id
    ...
    // register ContentObserver to receive download progress, I query the status in `onChage` methord.
    getContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
             Uri.parse("content://downloads/my_downloads"), true, mDownLoadChangeObserver);
});
```

**My problem is:**

Stay in the fragment, it works fine. 
The the status can be queried until download success;
Quit the fragment, the download still works fine;
But if I enter the fragment when the `DownloadManager` is still downloading, It goes to query the download status. The status queried is right--`DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING`. But it turns to `DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED` immediately with the COLUMN_REASON 470.

How to solve it?